# Perl invalid argument when saving file

Tags: perl

I want to compare contents of two files in my script. In order to do so I'm loading files into arrays. First file contains unique names that I'm searching in second file. Problem isn't related to comparing, but then I have to save results into file, which name contains values from `@unique_names` array. Error appears in line where I'm creating file after comparison. 
Example of `$file_name` contents: `PT_FCT_Sales_20161003.out` and result of `print $outputFolder . $ file_name` is `c:\Strawberry\PT_FCT_Sales_20161003.out`

```
foreach my $file (@Files){
    if ($file =~ /out$/i){
        if ($file =~ /PT_FCT_Sales_/i){
            open(my $INFILE,  "<", $file) or die $!;

            @lines = <$INFILE>;

            foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @unique_names; $i++) {
                my $file_name = join('', @unique_names[$i]);
                #print $file_name;
                my @data;
                foreach $line (@lines) {
                    if ($line =~ @unique_names[$i] ) {
                        push (@data, $line);
                    }
                }

                open(my $OUTFILE, ">>", $outputFolder . $file_name) or die $!; #error appears here
                print $OUTFILE @data;
                close $OUTFILE;

            }
            close $INFILE or die "Can't close input file";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Error says: Invalid argument at test.pl line 71,  line 6.
Please note this isn't whole script, just a cut off related to the problem.

Comment: The description of the problem is completely unclear to me.  What error are you getting?  Also, _please_ `use warnings;` (and `use strict;`) -- with it you'd be warned against the _slice_ `@unique_names[$i]`, which should be the scalar `$unique_names[$i]`.

Comment: Why are you doing an if statement within an if statement and then again a foreach for the same array you did a foreach earlier? You are creating unnecessary loops. `$outputfolder` is used only once? `@uniquenames[$i] can be written as `$uniquenames[$I]` @files only used once, where is the rest of the script?

Comment: @zdim I'm using `strict` and `warnings`, but I ignored warning. After correction, it still doesn't work. Please read update to my post

Comment: Alright -- that would've not been the reason.  But do use `$array[$i]`, I don't know of a reason not to.

Comment: again, how must we know where line 71 is? where is the rest of the script? or at least indicate where line 71 is.

Comment: To be honest it's my first touch with perl. 
Line 71 is `open(my $OUTFILE, ">>", $outputFolder . $file_name) or die $!;`, please see comment in code above. I can upload whole code, but I don't think it's necessary since I checked values in arrays, and they are correct. I think this might be some trivial error, that I cannot see

Comment: ok, show me where $outputfolder is defined

Comment: @Dodzik  I don't see anything ... the error means that `$outputFolder . $file_name` doesn't translate into a valid file name at all.  Is the location you show a valid path?

Comment: @Dodzik  Another comment, just so.  Since you don't use `$i`, iterate over the names: `foreach my $uniq_file (@unique_names) { ... }`.

Comment: @Dodzik A comment.  You can do: `my @data = grep { /$uniq_file/ } @lines;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a slightly better solution. Untested. so will edit and fix as I go along. Please provide where $outputfolder is defined.

```
foreach my $file (@Files){
if ($file =~ /^PT_FCT_Sales.*\.out$/i){
        open(my $INFILE,  "<", $file) or die $!;
        @lines = <$INFILE>;
        foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @unique_names; $i++) {
            my $file_name = join('', $unique_names[$i]);
            my @data;
            while (<$INFILE>) {
                if ($line =~ $unique_names[$i] ) {
                    push (@data, $line);
                }
            }
            open(my $OUTFILE, ">> $outputFolder.$file_name") or die $!; #error appears here
            print $OUTFILE @data;
            close $OUTFILE;

            }
            close $INFILE or die "Can't close input file";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually `">> $outputFolder.$file_name"` solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: awesome. try to also use the first if as I did, it will reduce the number of loops created. that will effectively match $file with  `PT_FCT_Sales*.out`

Comment: I'd change that to `open(my $OUTFILE, '>>', "$outputFolder.$file_name") or die ...`. The three-argument version of `open()` is inherently safer.